# H2 database files disappear

Tags: h2

After finishing some integration tests I found that my expected H2 database files did not exist.

With a url of "jdbc:h2:/tmp/casper" I expected to have a /tmp/casper.mv.db file however there was none.

The reason is that while initializing the database I used "drop all objects delete files"  After all my work, it disappeared after the test when the datasource was closed.

Demonstration in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

package org.javautil.h2;

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class H2DropAllObjectsTest {


    @Test
    public void casper() throws Exception {
        final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:/tmp/casper");
        config.setUsername("sr");
        config.setPassword("tutorial");
        config.setAutoCommit(true);

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        File f = new File("/tmp/casper.mv.db");
        assertTrue (f.exists());
        Statement s = connection.createStatement();

        s.execute("drop all objects delete files");
        assertTrue (f.exists());
        s.execute("create table a (b number(9))");
        /* do a lot of work */
        connection.commit();
        s.close();
        connection.close();
        assertTrue (f.exists());

        dataSource.close();

        assertFalse (f.exists());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just handle your database as `update` don't use `create/drop`

```
dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
```